Compatibility of react-native-maps 1.18.0 with Maps SDKs
I’m currently working on a React Native project. I’m having trouble finding specific information about which versions of the Google Maps SDK for Android and iOS are compatible with/correspond to which version of react-native-maps.
Where can I find that info?
